# Next step in proof of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Proposition to prove : (A-B)∩(B-A) = 0

So, I understand why this is 0, I'm just not sure what propositions should be used in proving so.

I have this so far
1)(A-B)∩(B-A)            :Premise
2)(A∩B')∩(B∩A')          :Alternative Representation for Set Diff.

My question is, Is this allowed:
3)(A)∩(A')∩(B)∩(B')     :?
4)0∩0                   :Intersection and Union with Complement
5)0                     :Intersection with 0

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to go to step 3, from step 2. And if I'm not able to do so, what process should I go about next in proving so?n
*I need to use laws/identities. I've already written a proof that does "element chasing" (let x be a number...)

Comment: You are right. The intersection of sets is associative, so your third step is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Looks legal to me. Set intersection is associative and commutative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are supposed to use to prove this, but the easiest way is to assume that there is an element in the intersection, and then show that this element is not in $B$ and not in $A$, but it also has to be in both of them.

Comment: I'm supposed to prove this twice. One proof is supposed to use the laws/definitions of sets, and the other is an "element chasing" proof. In my element chasing proof, I've already done what you explained. I now need to prove it using the laws/identities